# Alternate Compiler for Installing R Packages: clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Tags: java, r, compiler-errors

I am trying to install the rJava package on OS X 10.11.6 with R version 3.4.0:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = "source")
```

and I get the following error:

```
clang -o libjri.jnilib Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -dynamiclib -framework JavaVM -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv    
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
```

From what I can tell, clang is being used as the compiler, using 'fopenmp' which doesn't appear to be supported by clang.  Can anyone see a way around this, potentially forcing a different compiler to be used? (note: I know almost nothing about compilers)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

This is caused because R 3.4.0 is compiled by CRAN with llvm-4.0.0 (which supports OpenMP), but Apple's fork (installed by default on macOS) does *not* support OpenMP. There are three solutions

1. Use the package binaries provided by CRAN, e.g. `install.packages(type = "binary")`.
2. Install a compiler that does support OpenMP, such as gcc or clang from hombrew, however you will also have to modify variables in your personal makevars file (`~/.R/Makevars`).
3. Unset `SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS` and `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS` in your `~/.R/Makevars`

For 2. you can install the compilers with `brew install llvm` or `brew install gcc --without-multilib` then you will have to add the compiler path to your `~/.R/Makevars` file.

```
CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
# Also potentially CXX11 (for C++11 compiler)
CXX11=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
```

or for `gcc` use (double check gcc executable exists and is correctly named)

```
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7
CXX=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7
# Also potentially CXX11 (for C++11 compiler)
CXX11=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7
```

Alternatively you can install a [CRAN Provided LLVM 4.0](http://r.research.att.com/libs/) and set the `Makevars` file appropriately.

For 3. you simply need to unset the `SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS`

```
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=
```

For more details see [OpenMP support](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support) in Writing R Extensions.

Note this error has nothing to do with Java or the rJava package in particular, so ideally the question could be renamed to `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`.

Comment: Any clue where my personal makevars file is? `$ cd ~/.R/Makevars
-bash: cd: /Users/me/.R/Makevars: No such file or directory`

Comment: There isn't one by default, you need to create the `~/.R/` directory and `Makevars` file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `R --quiet -e 'install.packages("rJava", type="binary", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'` from the command line got it for me.

Comment: Version 2. with clang did not work for me. But version 3. did!

Answer (score 0):

Running following in terminal fixes the package download in RStudio too and you can run the Rjava or r-app without any issues.

```
    brew cask install r-app 
    brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49 --without-multilib 
    sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
    brew link --overwrite --force gcc49
    brew unlink gcc49 && brew link gcc49
    brew install llvm
    mkdir ~/.R; touch ~/.R/Makevars
```