# Preparing for CRAN: '-fopenmp' clang error?

Tags: r, clang, travis-ci, rcpp, cran

I am preparing a package (which makes use of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo) for submission to CRAN. I am using Travis CI and I have included the following to test my package more thoroughly:

```
os:
  - linux
  - osx
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
```

This, however, yields the (familiar, it seems) error when using `clang` on OS X

```
* installing *source* package ‘my_pkg’ ...
** libs
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Users/travis/R/Library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/travis/R/Library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pkg’
* removing ‘/Users/travis/build/my_user/pkg/pkg.Rcheck/pkg’
```

By appropriately adjusting my `travis.yml` file to adhere to one of the workarounds suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595457/alternate-compiler-for-installing-r-packages-error-installing-rjava), it seems like I can avoid the issue.

My question is: what should I do if I want to put this on CRAN? Jim's suggestions seems to me only local, do I have to do something in my package to automatically avoid the compile issue for the user in order to be accepted by CRAN?

Edit: To be a little bit more specific, could I just put `CXX=g++` in `Makevars`, or is that frowned upon (and would that be sufficient)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... one step at a time, please.  Which RcppArmadillo version are you pulling in here?  Which clang version are you pulling in?  Where is that clang version from?  Does it have OpenMP support?

Starting with the *previous* release of RcppArmadillo, we ensured we simply turn OpenMP *off* on macOS as the build support is too fragile, see [this PR on GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/pull/170).  So you may have to remove *unconditional* use of `-fopenmp` in your files, or simple not use that "cell" of your Matrix (ie clang && macOS).

Otherwise, the [answer by Jim Hester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595457/alternate-compiler-for-installing-r-packages-error-installing-rjava) is spot-on.  Things are just more work on macOS.

Comment: Travis is using R 3.4.2, Rcpp 0.12.13 and RcppArmadillo 0.7.960.1.2. I'm not sure what clang version it's using, it simply says "On OS X, the version of clang is controlled by the choice of osx_image", but I'm unable to find what versions this results in. As far as I'm aware, I'm not using OpenMP in my code unless it's automatically enabled for some things. My main concern is that while I might as well skip the clang && macOS part of the matrix (or e.g. set the SHLIB_OPENMP* flags to empty, as suggested by Jim), will this bite me in the behind when submitting to CRAN later?

Comment: Given that there are newer versions of RcppArmadillo available, would it be sufficient just to add a version requirement to Imports?

Comment: No, the brand-new 0.8.100.1.0 does the same logic.  We had to add additional dances too, see [our configure script](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/a97fa6f42235d98ffca7e1c5e2a168f014639688/configure.ac#L88-L110) but I have not needed that for packages of mine using RcppArmadillo.  There are _405_ CRAN using RcppArmadillo giving you usage examples---AFAIK none do anything special and none are blocked.

Comment: I see, thanks! It seems easier and less awkward to put the problem on the user, who would just need to follow steps such as those laid out by Jim. Needless to say, I'd rather not go down the dancing route...

Comment: I wish it wasn't such a boiling mess but we are between a "rock" (Conrad turning OpenMP on automatically on modern-enough compilers) and a "hard place" (macOS and its inability of providing OpenMP consistently _and_ the choice by R Core / CRAN to now use their own compiler with OpenMP).

Comment: Missing the key component of compiler _not_ providing a good way to detect OpenMP c.f. `AC_OPENMP` doesn't pick up the proper flags and defaults to it being missing :/