# RcppArmadillo: Using autoconf to disable OpenMP

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In a comment by Dirk to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705491/preparing-for-cran-fopenmp-clang-error), I was pointed to the `configure.ac` script used by RcppArmadillo in order to programatically at build time check whether there is support for OpenMP on OS X. I then thought that sounded too complicated and unncessary for me, but I tried some things to avoid the OpenMP issue but it still seems to remain when I test it on Travis.

So what I have done now is this:

#### 1. configure.ac

I have (somewhat blatantly, but I will of course honor the GPL-2 license) copied the [configure.ac](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/a97fa6f42235d98ffca7e1c5e2a168f014639688/configure.ac) script used by RcppArmadillo, removed some parts (`LAPACK` check, for instance) and adjusted names and so on to my package

#### 2. Makevars

Renamed `src/Makevars` to `src/Makevars.in` and it now reads

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/include @OPENMP_FLAG@
PKG_LIBS= @OPENMP_FLAG@ $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

and `src/Makevars.win`

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/include -I. $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

#### 3. cleanup

Added a `cleanup` file containing

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f config.* src/Makevars src/config.h inst/include/pkgConfigGenerated.h
```

#### 4. pkgConfigGenerated.h

Added a file `inst/include/pkgConfigGenerated.h.in` which is like so:

```
#ifndef pkg__pkgConfigGenerated__h
#define pkg__pkgConfigGenerated__h
@HAVE_OPENMP@
#endif
```

#### 5. pkgConfig.h

Based on the `RcppArmadilloConfig.h` file, I created `inst/include/pkgConfig.h` as

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
   #define ARMA_USE_OPENMP
#else
   #include <pkgConfigGenerated.h>
#endif
```

My questions:

- Now I'm guessing I will need to add `#include <pkgConfig.h>`
  to my cpp files in `src` as this is how I believe RcppArmadillo uses it. Is this correct? When I test it on Linux, it complains about not finding it: `fatal error: pkgConfig.h: No such file or directory`. Is there some additional linking I need to do?
- Do I need to do anything else?

---

## A working solution

Based on Dirk's answer, I did the following. I borrowed the `configure.ac` file from `RcppArmadillo` and included the part I needed with minor changes (I include all of it here for future references):

```
## Copyright Dirk Eddelbuettel for RcppArmadillo (GPL-2)
AC_PREREQ(2.61)
AC_INIT([pkg], 0.1.0)

: ${R_HOME=$(R RHOME)}
if test -z "${R_HOME}"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not determine R_HOME.])
fi

CXX=$(${R_HOME}/bin/R CMD config CXX)
CXXFLAGS=$("${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXXFLAGS)

AC_LANG(C++)
AC_REQUIRE_CPP

openmp_flag=""
openmp_cflag=""

AC_MSG_CHECKING([for macOS])
RSysinfoName=$("${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript" --vanilla -e 'cat(Sys.info()[["sysname"]])')
if test x"${RSysinfoName}" == x"Darwin"; then
   AC_MSG_RESULT([found])
   AC_MSG_WARN([OpenMP unavailable and turned off.])
   openmp_flag="-DARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP"
else
   AC_MSG_RESULT([not found as on ${RSysinfoName}])
   AC_MSG_CHECKING([for OpenMP])
   allldflags=$(${R_HOME}/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
   hasOpenMP=$(echo ${allldflags} | grep -- -fopenmp)
   if test x"${hasOpenMP}" == x""; then
      AC_MSG_RESULT([missing])
      openmp_flag="-DARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP"
   else
      AC_MSG_RESULT([found])
      openmp_flag='$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)'
      openmp_cflag='$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)'
   fi
fi

AC_SUBST([OPENMP_CFLAG], ["${openmp_cflag}"])
AC_SUBST([OPENMP_FLAG], ["${openmp_flag}"])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/Makevars])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**My main mistake was that I thought that `autoconf` was automatically called on this `configure.ac` file to obtain `configure`, but it was not!**

The corresponding `Makevars.in` is

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = @OPENMP_FLAG@
PKG_LIBS= @OPENMP_CFLAG@ $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

(Maybe the two flags could be simplified to one, but don't fix what ain't broken...)

Now I get passing builds on both Linux and OS X (except OS X and `devel` version of R when `RcppArmadillo` fails to be installed, but that seems to be a different issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One to four seem fine; I don't even think you need two files. Just set `ARMA_USE_OPENMP` *or* its complement `ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP`.

Come to think about it, that could also just be added to the compilation flags via `-DARMA_USE_OPENMP` or `-DARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP`, respectively.

Five is a little troubling in that you don't seem to know how to set an include flag.  More reasons not to rely on extra files, eh?  ;-)

Let's see how this goes.  We could decide to help to offer an R-level function you may call from a script `configure` (which could then be in bash, or use `Rscript`).

*Edit:* Just realized a much simpler fix you *could* use: simply impose C++98 as the compilation standard.  As *Writing R Extensions* says:

> Conversely, to ensure that the C++98 standard is assumed even when
>   this is not the compiler default, use
>
> ```
>  SystemRequirements: C++98
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>  CXX_STD = CXX98
> ```

This will also turn off Armadillo's preference for OpenMP which is always on under C++11.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit I don't know what I'm doing *at least* half of the time. My understanding of having two files is that configure is not used on Windows, so if I'd just refer to `pkgConfigGenerated.h` that would not work as it wouldn't exist on Windows. I realized now that I forgot to wrap the whole thing in 5. in `#ifndef pkg__pkgConfig__h ...`, but I'm not sure if that would fix it? (I guess you know, though...!) I'll try it and see. FWIW, if the package skeleton in RcppArmadillo could set this whole thing up, that would be a dream.

Comment: Point taken re skeleton. I have a minor update pending there anyway.

Comment: I thought about this some more last night and I have two follow-up questions. First: do you mean that I can skip the pkgConfig*.h files altogether? The configure script will set the variable in Makevars, and is that simply sufficient? Second: what *exactly* am I doing wrong with respect to #include? I tried to mimic RcppArmadillo as much as possible, but I’m unable to see where I went wrong (as I said, at least half of the time I don’t know what I’m doing :-)).

Comment: Curiously, the C++98 way does not seem to work for me as I get the same error (`unsupported option -fopenmp`). I managed to get it working on OS X by skipping the pkgConfig*.h files and adjusting the have_openmp variable in configure.ac to be `-DARMA_USE_OPENMP` or the opposite and then having `PKG_CXXFLAGS = @HAVE_OPENMP@` in `Makevars.in`. However, then I broke the compilation on Linux as I started getting `"undefined symbol": dgels_`. So I don't know, for now I might just skip all of this and let potential mac users deal with this themselves.

Comment: My harassing ends: now! See my edit in the original post. My mistake was basically just to assume that autoconf was called on the `configure.ac` file, while it wasn't. Thank you a lot for the help (and all of your work for the R community)!

Comment: Yes:  One writes `configure.ac` (generally short), then (explicitly) calls `autoconf` to produce `configure` (generally long and unreadable) and ships both `configure.ac` (as source) and `configure`.  R only runs the latter.  *Now*, the real trick is that `configure` can be _any_ executable script, including a shell script of a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

See my remarks in the [PR](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/pull/170#issuecomment-336013964) you linked:

> (Being unable to use OpenMP) is only the case for *RcppArmadillo*. Using OpenMP on macOS with *Rcpp* is possible via `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]`. Though, you need to be wary of the dragons that exist since *R* is single threaded.
>
> You can manually regain OpenMP (in RcppArmadillo) by modifying the local install of *RcppArmadillo*'s `inline.R` to include `-fopenmp` and removing the [`#define ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP 1`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/a97fa6f42235d98ffca7e1c5e2a168f014639688/configure.ac#L104) in [`inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/a97fa6f42235d98ffca7e1c5e2a168f014639688/inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h.in#L29)

So, the issue you are running into with the Travis build is the binary build of [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) (from CRAN) has disabled OpenMP permanently on the macOS build.

Writing your *own* configuration script for your *R* package *will not* override the `RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h` file included in the installed [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) package. This file is subsequently called by `RcppArmadillo.h`. The only way this can be changed is if upstream [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) is modified, which in turn relies on Base *R* providing the appropriate OpenMP detection hooks.

Comment: But if RcppArmadillo disables OpenMP and I do the same in my package, it should work, right? All I want is for my package to compile on OS X, with or without OpenMP. If you have other suggestions on how to do this easily so that it compiles on OS X without any additional hassle on the user side, I'd gladly hear them!

Comment: I'm a bit tied up right now. I'll revisit later today / on Saturday.